# Detect Escape on keyPress

Tags: c#, keypress

I want to detect Escape on a field in C# to add '_'. I tested `e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape`, but it's not working. Have you an idea?

```cs
private void tbxLibelle_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        tbxNomimage.Text += '_';
    }
    else
    {
        tbxNomimage.Text = tbxLibelle.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `KeyCode` from [KeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event, `KeyPressEventArgs` provide only the `KeyChar` property. `KeyCode` can get from the `KeyDown` event. `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` has the required `KeyCode` property:

```
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                tbxNomimage.Text += '_';
            }
            else
            {
                tbxNomimage.Text = tbxLibelle.Text;
            }
        }
```

If the `KeyDown` event is not suit, you can save the `KeyCode` in global private field.

```
        private Keys key_Code;
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.key_Code == Keys.Escape)
            {
                tbxNomimage.Text += '_';
            }
            else
            {
                tbxNomimage.Text = tbxLibelle.Text;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.key_Code = e.KeyCode;
        }
```

[Key events occur in the following order:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

- KeyDown
- KeyPress
- KeyUp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: I'd note that the examples in the link you provide to [`KeyPressEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples) do show how you can check for escape = `e.KeyChar == (char)27`. This is probably preferable to saving to a field from another event.

Comment: @CharlesMager use KeyDown event..

Comment: Yes, that is one of your suggestions. I'm pointing out that if they need to use the `KeyPress` event, then checking `e.KeyChar` would be far more straightforward than saving the key from the `KeyDown` event.